# Porblems when applying textEmbed function with RoBERTa on some texts

Tags: r, r-text

I have been using the package text since a couple of days. Everything works fine as far as you call BERT or Electra for example. However when I try to call "roberta-base" or "xlm-roberta-base" to work on some texts I get very often an error.

Example of a text that creates problems:

"627% but if they had lower striked than 16 I would have gone even further OTM. This could really fall off a cliff."

I keep getting the following error: Error in `dplyr::bind_cols()`: ! Can't recycle `..1` (size 44) to match `..2` (size 32).

And if I go with the backtrace I get the following explanation:

Backtrace:

```
     ▆
  1. ├─base::system.time(embeddings_CL2 <- textEmbed(xx, model = "roberta-base"))
  2. ├─text::textEmbed(xx, model = "roberta-base")
  3. │ └─text::textEmbedRawLayers(...)
  4. │   └─text:::sortingLayers(x = hg_embeddings, layers = layers, return_tokens = return_tokens)
  5. │     └─dplyr::bind_cols(tokens_layer_number, layers_4_token)
  6. │       └─vctrs::vec_cbind(!!!dots, .name_repair = .name_repair, .error_call = current_env())
  7. └─vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
  8.   └─vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
  9.     └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
 10.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)
```

Any idea why?
Thanks
Best
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using text_0.9.99.8 from Github (https://github.com/OscarKjell/text).

```
test_text <- "627% but if they had lower striked than 16 I would have gone even further OTM. This could really fall off a cliff."

test_emb <- textEmbed(test_text,
                      model = "roberta-base")
```

Comment: Right! Thanks. I was getting the above error by employing the CRAN version. With the 0.9.99.8 from Github everything is fine. Thanks!